# Erlang 'catch' expression vs try/catch in terms of efficiency

Tags: performance, exception, erlang, runtime-error, processing-efficiency

A similar question was asked about this but it was not exactly asked in the same terms.

I am trying to safely decode base64 binaries, in a context where it's possible the input will not be a binary, or even base64 encoded.

Erlang says let it crash and handle it -- if I were to do this, what is the most efficient way. Efficiency is quite important in this system.

I know to avoid try/catch, as it builds a full stack trace -- however, is the catch keyword reasonable for this context? And is the catch keyword faster/more efficient?

In a function such as

```
safe_decode(Binary) ->
    case catch base64:decode(Binary) of
        <<Result/binary>> -> {ok, Result};
        {'EXIT', _} -> {not_base64, Binary}
    end.
```

Is this truly more efficient than a try catch? How best to handle this scenario in a system where efficiency is important i.e. crashes which involve building a stack trace and/or require more processing than the happy path need to be handled as efficiently as possible.

I'm just learning erlang, so maybe the answer is staring me in the face.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's the other way around: avoid `catch` since it always builds a stack trace.  `try`+`catch` only builds a stack trace if you ask it to with `erlang:get_stacktrace()`.

See [Heads-up: The cost of get_stacktrace()](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-November/075928.html), posted to erlang-questions by Richard Carlsson on 2013-11-05, for the full story.  Let me cite a few parts:

> (Executive summary: exceptions cheap, but erlang:get_stacktrace() kind 
>   of expensive; also, avoid 'catch Expr'.)

> It's of course still valid to call get_stacktrace() in many situations, 
>   e.g. when the process is on its way to give up, or to write the crash 
>   information to a log, or for something that only happens rarely and the 
>   stack trace information is useful - but never in a library function that 
>   might be used heavily in a loop.

> Finally, this is also another reason to rewrite old occurrences of 
>   'catch Expr' into 'try Expr catch ... end' [...]

Comment: You may also want to `spawn_monitor` a painlessly crashable process that will either send you a message of success or a death note (the monitor) on failure straight away without encouraging any `try..catch` madness. *Sometimes* this is the ideal solution. Sometimes not. As always, benchmark. If you are catching a *lot* of bad input data then the crashes may be a lighter load. If 99% of your input data is good, then `try..catch` is probably better.